# Increasing Number of Rows when Array Refreshed in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to currently create a page where it displays a number of records based on what a number a user inputs - e.g. If user inputs 5, only 5 records are shown.

How it works is that in my HTML, I've got a for:each to iterate and display templates based on the array 'filteredWords'. This is an array containing a series of objects

```
<template>
    <input min="0" max={maxWords} type="number" value={numFiltered} onchange={handleNumFiltered}>
    <template for:each={filteredWords} for:item="word" for:index="index">

        <lightning-layout-item key={word.Id}>
            <lightning-card>
                {word.Name}
            </lightning-card>

        </lightning-layout-item>
    </template>
</template>
```

Here's the js file for reference. The main function handling the refresh for the number of records to show is **handleNumFiltered**. My issue is this:

- When the page first loads, the number of records shown loads correctly (e.g. 5)
- When I reduce the number of records to show on the page (e.g. to 1) the number of records rendered decreases as intended
- The problem comes in when I increase the number of records beyond the initial number. E.g. If I increase the records to 6, 7, 8, etc (above 5), the number of records will remain at 5 (or at the lower number I filtered)

How do I fix this?

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAllWords from '@salesforce/apex/JapaneseController.getAllWords';
export default class Japanese extends LightningElement {
    allWords;
    maxWords;
    orderedWords;
    filteredWords;
    numFiltered = 5;
    error;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.loadWords();
    }
    shuffle(array) {
        let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (currentIndex != 0) {

            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex--;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
                array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
        }

        return array;
    }
    loadWords() {
        getAllWords()
            .then(result => {
                this.allWords = result;
                this.filteredWords = [...result];
                this.maxWords = result.length;
                this.filteredWords = this.shuffle(this.filteredWords).slice(0, this.numFiltered);
            }).catch(error => { this.error = error })
    }
    handleNumFiltered(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.numFiltered = event.target.value;
        this.filteredWords = [...this.shuffle(this.filteredWords).slice(0, event.target.value)];
        console.log(this.filteredWords);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `loadWords` function you store the whole result in `allWords` and just the requested number of words in `filteredWords`.
Then `handleNumFiltered` function modify only `filteredWords`, which has at most 5 values since that's the default.
In order to show the requested number of words you should shuffle `allWords` array in `handleNumFiltered`:

```js
handleNumFiltered(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.numFiltered = event.target.value;
    this.filteredWords = this.shuffle([...this.allWords]).slice(0, event.target.value);
    console.log(this.filteredWords);
}
```